# Is O(1) a Lie Group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups

In reading Georgi (Lie algebra in particle physics) I reaf at page 43 the following definition of Lie Gruoup: "a lie gruoup is a group whose elements depend smoothly on a set of continuous parameters."
$\phi$
Wikipedia says that $O(n)$ in a Lie group.
For $n\geq2$ this is intuitive (for example elements of $O(2)$ are parametrized by one parameter $\phi$, while elements of $O(3)$ are parametrized by two parameters $\theta, \phi$ and so on.
My question is: in case of $O(1)$ I have that the group has only two elements (in its fundamental representation the real numbers $+1 $ and $ -1$ but I cannot see how to parametrize those elements with a continuous parameter...Hence is $O(1)$ a Lie group?

Moreover what is the difference between Z2 and O(1)?
(this last question arises because I read in a book that Ising 1D model has Z2 symmetry and in another section of that book I read that Ising 1D model has O(1) symmetry [when seen as case n=1 of the O(n) model]

Comment: $C_2$ and $O(1)$ are the same group, but the latter carries some metadata about where the group came from (namely, symmetries in geometry or somesuch). It is useful to keep track of such metadata.

Comment: Part of the problem is that the "definition" you're quoting is not really a mathematically rigorous definition of a Lie group. Here's the real definition: A _Lie group_ is a group (in the algebraic sense) that is also a smooth manifold, such that multiplication and inversion are smooth maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any discrete space $X$ is a $0$-dimensional smooth manifold. Any $x\in X$ has a nbhd $\{x\}$ with the obvious chart from $\{x\}$ to the Euclidean space $\Bbb R^0=\{0\}$. These charts are the only ones possible in the atlas, and there is only one possible transition map $\{0\}\to\{0\}$, which is vacuously smooth.

Comment: So is there any precise relationship between Lie groups and discrete grups? Can I say that all discrete groups are 0-parameters Lie Groups?

Comment: @Caso: yes, but only in the same degenerate way that all line segments are triangles. The interesting case is positive dimension, and in practice most examples have finitely many connected components.